# Help with PHP and filepaths

Tags: php, zend-framework, include-path

I am using windows right now but I need my script to work on windows or linux.  I am working on a project which allows to upload video to youtube, the youtube library requires the use of Zend framework (unfortunately) so I am really trying to get it to work, with no luck.

So my page says

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No 
such file or directory in 
E:\Server\htdocs\clients\youtube2\demos\Zend\Gdata\YouTubeVideoApp\operations.php on line 37
```

I have Zend framework located at

```
E:\Server\htdocs\frameworks\Zend
```

I then try to set the include path so that the scripts have access to Zend, thats where my trouble starts.  I try to use this...

```
$path = 'E:/Server/htdocs/frameworks/Zend/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

But I still get the error that you see above, now that you can see the path of my script above and the path of my Zend, can someone show me how to set the include path to work correctly?  Thanks for any help

---

### I tried some suggestions with no luck so far.  Here is my updated code and result

```
$path = 'E:\Server\htdocs\frameworks';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
echo get_include_path();
```

Gives this...

```
E:\Server\php\PEAR;E:\Server\htdocs\frameworks
```

So it appears my include path for zend is added, but it still says it cannot find it

---

### Final Update!

It is working,  just where I set the include path wasn't getting included into all the files, is there a way to set the include path and have it be available globally?

Comment: The `Zend/Loader.php` file is located at `E:\Server\htdocs\frameworks\Zend\Zend\Loader.php`, with two `Zend` directories?

Comment: Linux doesn't use drive letters `E:`

Comment: @Radu no just 1 zend directory `E:\Server\htdocs\frameworks\Zend\Loader.php`

Comment: @jasondavis, then your `$path` should be `E:/Server/htdocs/frameworks`, not `E:/Server/htdocs/frameworks/Zend`.

Comment: @Radu, I just tried that but doesnt have any affect

Comment: @jasondavis, are you sure the include path gets set? If you `echo` the value of `get_include_path()` right before your `include` statement, is it showing the correct paths?

Comment: @Radu, yes I just realized it is working now, i just need it to be set globally somehow, is there somewhere I can set include paths and have all files see that?

Comment: @jasondavis, only if you have access to `php.ini`. Otherwise, you'll just have to include a `config.php` file that does this.

Comment: I have access to it, do you know what I need to change? thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the include path in `php.ini`, just change `include_path`. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html) to find out about a myriad of ways of changing the include path.

Answer (score 2):

```
E:\Server\htdocs\frameworks\Zend
```

versus

```
$path = 'E:/Server/htdocs/frameworks/Zend/';
```

might make a difference on your system? Try it with `\` instead of `/`.

Comment: It might be that you're trying to include `E:/Server/htdocs/frameworks/Zend/Zend/Loader.php` then, cause thats what your code does

Comment: It is working, is there a way to set the include path and have it be set for all files